# Parallax not working with Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, parallax, skrollr

I'm trying to recreate this demo in my own Rails project:
http://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/parallax-scroll-effect/

Files are here: http://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/parallax-scroll-effect-1302.zip

But it only shows the last slide and not scrollable. I suspect there's something wrong with loading the js files in Rails but I'm not entirely sure.

Here is my repo: https://github.com/tihuan/parallaxtest. You can clone it and run `rails s` to see that it's broken.

*Note that you can remove requiring js files from Welcome#index.html.erb since I already added them in application.js!

** Current application.js loading order:

```
//= require js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min
//= require js/vendor/modernizr-2.7.1.min
//= require js/skrollr
//= require js/imagesloaded
//= require js/_main
//= require_tree .
```

Please help!

Comment: What does the browser console say?

Comment: It shows "undefined is not a function" -- pointing to main.js. But I could recreate the same error with the demo files by requiring main.js in the html page, and the parallax effect would still work.

Comment: Mmh, it might be the way you are loading them, is modernizr set properly?

Comment: I think you need this configuration in your application.html https://github.com/russfrisch/modernizr-rails, to load modernizr the right way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be thaat your not loading the scripts in the right way, check [modernizr config](https://github.com/russfrisch/modernizr-rails) and how you need to load it into the app

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Your Awesome App</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    :application, media: :all %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag :modernizr %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body>
  ...
    <%= javascript_include_tag :application %>
  </body>
</html>`
```